# how to run a function for the length of a document

Tags: python, function

The following code results in 2\n 4\n 6\n 8\n.

```
with open('test.csv','r')as document:
    for line in document:
        line=line.split(',')
        for item in line:
            item=item.replace('\n','')
            item=int(item)*2
            print(item)
```

However, when I try to use it as a function as follows the result is only 2.

```
def results():
    with open('test.csv','r')as document:
        for line in document:
            line=line.split(',')
            for item in line:
                item=item.replace('\n','')
                item=int(item)*2
                return item

print(results())
```

Presumably this is only running the function once.  How can one go about running the function for the length of the document?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a list to append your items to. Your function only runs through each of the loops once because you `return` on the first iteration.

```
def results():
    items = list()
    with open('test.csv','r')as document:
        for line in document:
            line=line.split(',')
            for item in line:
                item=item.replace('\n','')
                item=int(item)*2
                items.append(item)
    return items

In [6]: results()
Out[6]: [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Or you could keep the same logic and use `yield` to create a generator:

```
def results():
    with open('test.csv','r')as document:
        for line in document:
            line=line.split(',')
            for item in line:
                item=item.replace('\n','')
                item=int(item)*2
                yield item


In [4]: [i for i in results()]
Out[4]: [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Note, this latter example keeps the file open until the generator is cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

You are not iterating over the lines of the file correctly. The following code will read a cvs file and return an array of arrays with each value squared. For example if the input file looked like:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

the output would be:

```
[[1,4,9],[16,25,36],[49,64,81]]
```

See example:

```
def results():
    arrayOfResults = []
    with open('test.csv','r')as document:
        lines = document.read().split("\n")
        for line in lines:
            items=line.split(',')
            resultsForThisLine = []
            for item in items:
                resultsForThisLine.append(int(item)**2)
            arrayOfResults.append(resultsForThisLine)
print(arrayOfResults)
```

Notice that we read and split the input file before itterating over the lines and that we create an array of results for each row, as well as an array for he table as a whole to which we append the array for each row.

Not sure if this is exactly what you are trying to do but what you posted looked pretty weird...